# Convert Number into Word in C# window

Tags: c#

I am trying to Convert Number into Word in C# windows. My code is :

```
namespace Num2Text
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = changeToWords(textBox1.Text, false);
        }
        public String changeNumericToWords(double numb)
        {
            String num = numb.ToString();
            return changeToWords(num, false);
        }
        public String changeCurrencyToWords(String numb)
        {
            return changeToWords(numb, true);
        }
        public String changeNumericToWords(String numb)
        {
            return changeToWords(numb, false);
        }
        public String changeCurrencyToWords(double numb)
        {
            return changeToWords(numb.ToString(), true);
        }
        private String changeToWords(String numb, bool isCurrency)
        {
            String val = "", wholeNo = numb, points = "", andStr = "", pointStr = "";
            String endStr = (isCurrency) ? ("Only") : ("Only"); //-- Only-- 
            try
            {
                int decimalPlace = numb.IndexOf(".");
                if (decimalPlace > 0)
                {
                    wholeNo = numb.Substring(0, decimalPlace);
                    points = numb.Substring(decimalPlace + 1);
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(points) > 0)
                    {
                        andStr = (isCurrency) ? ("and") : ("Point");// just to separate whole numbers from points/cents 
                        endStr = (isCurrency) ? ("Cents " + endStr) : ("Only"); //--Paisa Only-- 
                        pointStr = translateCents(points);
                    }
                }
                val = String.Format("{0} {1}{2} {3}", translateWholeNumber(wholeNo).Trim(), andStr, pointStr, endStr);
            }
            catch { ;}
            return val;
        }
        private String translateWholeNumber(String number)
        {
            string word = " "; //--Taka-- 
            try
            {
                bool beginsZero = false;//tests for 0XX 
                bool isDone = false;//test if already translated 
                double dblAmt = (Convert.ToDouble(number));
                //if ((dblAmt > 0) && number.StartsWith("0")) 
                if (dblAmt > 0)
                {//test for zero or digit zero in a nuemric 
                    beginsZero = number.StartsWith("0");
                    int numDigits = number.Length;
                    int pos = 0;//store digit grouping 
                    String place = " ";//digit grouping name:hundres,thousand,etc... 
                    switch (numDigits)
                    {
                        case 1://ones' range 
                            word = ones(number);
                            isDone = true;
                            break;
                        case 2://tens' range 
                            word = tens(number);
                            isDone = true;
                            break;
                        case 3://hundreds' range 
                            pos = (numDigits % 3) + 1;
                            place = " Hundred ";
                            break;
                        case 4://thousands' range 
                        case 5:
                        case 6:
                            pos = (numDigits % 4) + 1;//
                            place = " Thousand ";
                            break;
                        case 7://millions' range 
                        case 8:
                        case 9:
                            pos = (numDigits % 7) + 1;
                            place = " Million ";
                            break;
                        case 10://Billions's range 
                            case 11:
                            case 12:
                            pos = (numDigits % 10) + 1;
                            place = " Billion ";
                            break;
                        //add extra case options for anything above Billion... 
                        default:
                            isDone = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (!isDone)
                    {//if transalation is not done, continue...(Recursion comes in now!!) 
                        word = translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(0, pos)) + place + translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(pos));
                        //check for trailing zeros 
                        if (beginsZero) word = "  " + word.Trim();//-----"and"---
                    }
                    //ignore digit grouping names 
                    if (word.Trim().Equals(place.Trim())) word = "";
                }
            }
            catch { ;}
            return word.Trim();
        }
        private String tens(String digit)
        {
            int digt = Convert.ToInt32(digit);
            String name = null;
            switch (digt)
            {
                case 10:
                    name = "Ten";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    name = "Eleven";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    name = "Twelve";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    name = "Thirteen";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    name = "Fourteen";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    name = "Fifteen";
                    break;
                case 16:
                    name = "Sixteen";
                    break;
                case 17:
                    name = "Seventeen";
                    break;
                case 18:
                    name = "Eighteen";
                    break;
                case 19:
                    name = "Nineteen";
                    break;
                case 20:
                    name = "Twenty";
                    break;
                case 30:
                    name = "Thirty";
                    break;
                case 40:
                    name = "Fourty";
                    break;
                case 50:
                    name = "Fifty";
                    break;
                case 60:
                    name = "Sixty";
                    break;
                case 70:
                    name = "Seventy";
                    break;
                case 80:
                    name = "Eighty";
                    break;
                case 90:
                    name = "Ninety";
                    break;
                default:
                    if (digt > 0)
                    {
                        name = tens(digit.Substring(0, 1) + "0") + " " + ones(digit.Substring(1));
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return name;
        }
        private String ones(String digit)
        {
            int digt = Convert.ToInt32(digit);
            String name = "";
            switch (digt)
            {
                case 1:
                    name = "One";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    name = "Two";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    name = "Three";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    name = "Four";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    name = "Five";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    name = "Six";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    name = "Seven";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    name = "Eight";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    name = "Nine";
                    break;
            }
            return name;
        }
        private String translateCents(String cents)
        {
            String cts = "", digit = "", engOne = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < cents.Length; i++)
            {
                digit = cents[i].ToString();
                if (digit.Equals("0"))
                {
                    engOne = "Zero";
                }
                else
                {
                    engOne = ones(digit);
                }
                cts += " " + engOne;
            }
            return cts;
        }
```

[image]

It working to convert (from One to Billion). But there is a error ,when Hundred Position is null. <<>>

what is the right code ?

Comment: Make a dictionary with "One", "Two", "Three" and you'll get rid of 50% of your code.

Comment: `catch { }` is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the comparison against `beginsZero` to enable changing the `place` variable (to remove the 'Hundred', 'Thousand' etc.) when there is no digit between 1 and 9. So, like this:

```
//check for trailing zeros 
if (beginsZero)
{
    word = "  " + word.Trim();//-----"and"---
    place = ""; // Remove the current text as it is not required now
}

word = translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(0, pos)) + place +
translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(pos));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Steve Padmore . You are right. But I have a new problem  the word 'Thousand' is missing sometime. Now it showing number convert   into words;  Like as : 1010505 =One Million Ten(<<>>)Five Hundred Five Only.  Actually it will be One Million Ten   'Thousand' Five Hundred Five Only. I need more help please

Comment: Your best bet is to place some debug watches on the individual values used to build up the string. Then walk through each problem number and see where the value is being removed/added when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert number to word 0 - 9999.

```
public static string word(int number)
{
    string[] ones = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
    string[] tens = { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };
    string word = "";
    if (number == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ones[number]);
        word += ones[number];
    }
    if (number > 0 && number <=10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ones[number]);
        word += ones[number];
    }
    if(number > 10 && number <20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ones[number]);
        word += ones[number];
    }
    if (number >= 20 && number < 100)
    {
        int last = Math.Abs(number) % 10;
        if(last > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tens[number / 10] + " " + ones[last]);
            word += tens[number / 10] + " " + ones[last];
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tens[number / 10]);
            word += tens[number / 10];
        }
        
    }
    if (number >= 100 && number <= 9999)
    {
        int spliter = Math.Abs(number / 10) % 10;
        if(number.ToString().Length == 2) {
            if ((spliter / 100) % 10 > 10)
            {
                int first = number / 100;
                int second = Math.Abs(number / 10) % 10;
                word += ones[first] + " hundred " + tens[second];
                Console.WriteLine(word);
            }
            else
            {
                int first = number / 100;
                int second = Math.Abs(number / 10) % 10;
                word += ones[first] + " hundred " + tens[second] + " " + ones[Math.Abs(number) % 10];
                Console.WriteLine(word);
            }
        }
        else if (number.ToString().Length >= 3)
        {
            if ((number / 1000) % 10 > 0)
            {
                int first = number / 1000;
                int secondDigit = Math.Abs(number / 100) % 10;
                if (secondDigit > 0)
                {
                    int thirdDigit = Math.Abs(number / 100) % 10;
                    int lastDigit = Math.Abs(number / 1000) / 10;
                    if (thirdDigit > 0) {
                        if (lastDigit == 0)
                        {
                            // if number contains 0 at second to the last index
                            int last2Digit = Math.Abs(number) % 10;
                            int secondToTheLast = Math.Abs(number) / 10 % 10;
                            int thirdToTheLast = Math.Abs(number) % 100;
                            int lastTwoDigits = Math.Abs(number) % 100;
                            if (last2Digit > 0 && secondToTheLast > 0)
                            {
                                int lastTwoDigit = Math.Abs(number) % 100 / 10;
                                int last = Math.Abs(thirdToTheLast) % 10;

                                if (lastTwoDigits > 0 && lastTwoDigits < 20)
                                {
                                    word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " hundred " + ones[lastTwoDigits];
                                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                                }
                                else if(lastTwoDigits > 19)
                                {
                                    word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " hundred " + tens[lastTwoDigit] + " " + ones[last];
                                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                                }
                                                                    
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(lastTwoDigits == 00)
                                {
                                    word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " hundred ";
                                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if(lastTwoDigits < 10)
                                    {
                                        word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " hundred " + tens[secondToTheLast] + " " + ones[last2Digit];
                                        Console.WriteLine(word);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " hundred " + tens[secondToTheLast];
                                        Console.WriteLine(word);
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " hundred " + tens[thirdDigit] + " " + ones[Math.Abs(number / 100) % 10];
                            Console.WriteLine(word);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " hundred " + tens[thirdDigit] + ones[Math.Abs(number) % 100];
                        Console.WriteLine(word);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (
                        number == 1000
                        || number == 2000
                        || number == 3000
                        || number == 4000
                        || number == 5000
                        || number == 6000
                        || number == 7000
                        || number == 8000
                        || number == 9000
                     )
                    {
                        word += ones[number / 1000] + " thousand ";
                        Console.WriteLine(word);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int firstDigit = Math.Abs(Math.Abs(number) % 100) / 10;
                        int lastTwoDigit = Math.Abs(number)%100;
                        int firstDig = Math.Abs(lastTwoDigit / 10) % 100;
                        int last = Math.Abs(lastTwoDigit) % 10;
                        if (Math.Abs(number) % 10 == 0)
                        {
                            word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " " + tens[firstDigit];
                            Console.WriteLine(word);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(lastTwoDigit > 0 && lastTwoDigit < 20)
                            {
                                if(lastTwoDigit < 10)
                                {
                                    word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " " + ones[lastTwoDigit];
                                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " " + ones[lastTwoDigit];
                                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                                }
                                
                            }
                            else if(lastTwoDigit > 19)
                            {
                                word += ones[first] + " thousand " + ones[number / 100 % 10] + " " + tens[firstDig] + " "+ ones[last];
                                Console.WriteLine(word);
                            }                                

                        }
                        
                    }
                                           
                    
                }

            }
            else
            {
                int first = Math.Abs(number / 100) % 10;
                int middle = Math.Abs(number / 10) % 10;
                int last = Math.Abs(number) % 10;
                int last2Digit = Math.Abs(number) % 100;
                Console.WriteLine(middle);
                if (last2Digit > 0 && last2Digit < 20)
                {
                    if(last2Digit < 10)
                    {
                        word += ones[first] + " hundred " + tens[middle] + " " + ones[last2Digit];
                        Console.WriteLine(word);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        word += ones[first] + " hundred " + ones[last2Digit];
                        Console.WriteLine(word);
                    }
                    
                }
                else if (last2Digit > 19)
                {
                    word += ones[first] + " hundred " + tens[middle] + " " + ones[last];
                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                }
                else
                {
                    word += ones[first] + " hundred " + tens[middle] + ones[last];
                    Console.WriteLine(word);
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    else if (number >= 10000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Max number is 9999");
    }

    return word;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).